# Moving background image exceeds boundary of Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

My problem is shown below:

[image: Layout]

As the image moves left in the background, I do not want to see it outside of the red border of the canvas. In other words, I want the red box to be a window into the background image.

Is there a way to hide the parts of the image that exist outside of the red box?

My xaml is below:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,10,10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="460*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="668*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas x:Name="battlefieldBackground" Grid.Column="1">
            <Canvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="spaceBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="-3200" Duration="0:04:00" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Canvas.Triggers>
            <Image x:Name="spaceBackground" Source="Assets/SpaceBackground.jpg" Margin="0" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Border x:Name="battlefieldBorder" BorderThickness="3" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#FF810000"/>
        <!-- Xaml portion for gray grid -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set the Canvas' [`Clip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip.aspx) property.